# me sale este error: Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_curso\login.php on line 12

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un sistema con login y privilegios y me sale un error cuando voy a loguearme con el sistema:

Error:

> Notice: Undefined index: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login_curso\login.php on line 12

Dice que no esta definida la variable `password` pero si lo esta, aqui dejo la hoja donde esta supuestamente mal el codigo y gracias desde ya por la ayuda:

```
session_start();


require 'admin/config.php';
require 'functions.php';


$errores = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = hash('sha512', $password);

    $conexion = conexion($bd_config);
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password');
    $statement->execute([
        ':usuario' => $usuario,
        ':password' => $password

    ]);
    $resultado = $statement->fetch();

    if ($resultado !== false){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header('Location: '.RUTA.'index.php');

    } else{
        $errores .= '<li class="error">Tu usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectas</li>';

    }

}
require 'views/login.view.php';



?>
```

Comment: añade el código del HTML desde donde mandas la info que llega a este php

Comment: `$_POST['password']` no esta definido. Mira el contenido de POST para asegurarte de si lo escribiste correctamente: `var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es que no reconoce la variable $password, no esta reconociendo el index password ['password'], verifica si el nombre esta igual que el name en el html

Comment: muchas gracias, este era el error.